# VueJS v-for rendering list despite v-if evaluating to false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

According to the [vue js style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential),

> To avoid rendering a list if it should be hidden (e.g. v-for="user in users" v-if="shouldShowUsers"). In >these cases, move the v-if to a container element (e.g. ul, ol).

In my case, I am using v-for to render data in table rows but when the list is null, v-for still tries to access the null object's properties which leads to the following console error:

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'logo' of null"

Here's my HTML code

```
                        <tbody class="list" v-if="subscribers.length > 0">
                        <tr v-for="(subscriber, index) in subscribers" :key="index">
                            <th scope="row">
                                <div class="media align-items-center">
                                    <a href="#" class="avatar rounded-circle mr-3">
                                        <img alt="subscriber.logo" :src="`/img/avatars/${subscriber.logo}`">
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                        <span class="name mb-0 text-sm">{{subscriber.name}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <td>{{subscriber.email}}</td>
                            <td>{{subscriber.licenses}}</td>
                            <td>{{subscriber.status}}</td>
                            <td class="table-actions">
                                <a href="#!" class="table-action" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                   data-original-title="Edit">
                                    <i class="fas fa-user-edit" v-on:click="loadSubscriberEdit(index)"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#!" class="table-action table-action-delete" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                   data-original-title="Delete">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash" v-on:click="deleteSubscriber(index)"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a href="#!" v-bind:class="computeActiveActions(index)"
                                   :key="activeActionClassKey"
                                   data-toggle="tooltip"
                                   data-original-title="Delete">
                                    <i v-bind:class="computeActive(index)" :key="activeClassKey"
                                       v-on:click="toggleActivation(index)"></i>
                                </a>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tbody v-else>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="table-actions">No Subscriber found.</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

When subscribers list is null, the v-else block is rendered which works fine, however, the console still logs the above mentioned error

Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'logo' of null"

What can I do to stop v-for from trying to render if subscribers list is empty?

Comment: Could you clarify which of these 3 cases applies? 1. `subscribers` is `null`, 2. `subscribers` is an empty array, 3. `subscribers` is an array that contains the value `null`. In the question you've suggested that `subscribers` is `null`, but in that case `v-if="subscribers.length > 0"` should throw an error about trying to access the `length` property of `null`. Your `v-if` seems to be targeting case 2 but given the error message you're seeing it seems more likely you're in the 3rd case.

Comment: @skirtle, thanks for your response, my v-if targets case 2 as you rightly mentioned, for whatever reason the code now works without any error as before. I change anything. I'll test it again to be sure about this

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<!-- CASE 1 -->
 
 <!--div id="app">
    <table>
      <tbody v-if="false">
       if
      </tbody>
     <tbody v-else>
        else
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div-->



<!-- CASE 2 -->
<div id="app">
    <table>
      <tbody>
       <template v-if="false">
        if
       </template>
 <template >
        else
       </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

I know this is weird but for some reason, v-if doesn't seem to work with `tbody`.
Case 1 is the desired code and Case 2 is a work around

Comment: thanks @priyanshu sinha, actually, case 1 works for me.